# Write data in google spreadsheet using php curl?

Tags: php, curl, google-sheets

I am facing a little problem while writing in google spreadsheet.

I have created the class for writing the data in my app and it doesn't works, I have also created the class to fetch the spreadsheets and its working perfect.

I have tried the code by using curl and not the php spreadsheet library.

Here is my code

```
public function writeSheet($xml){

$headers = array(
"Authorization: Bearer {$this->AccessToken}",
"GData-Version: 3.0",
"Content-Type: application/atom+xml"
);

$curl = curl_init();
```

$url1="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/*****spreadsheetid*******/1/private/full";

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
exit();
```

}

On other file i am calling the function to write, here is code

```
$n = "dddddddd";
$y =  "bbbbbbbb";
$q =  "bbvccc";
$c =  "mfsdmjjioj";
$o =  "sdfdfds";
$op =  "bdfgdgdf";
$oq =  "gdfgdgteg";
$or =  "ggdvdger";
$os =  "verteved";

$xml = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
xmlns:gsx='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended'>
<gsx:DBA>dsajkn</gsx:DBA>
<gsx:BUSPHONE>sadjsahsan</gsx:BUSPHONE>
<gsx:NAME>dsadjksan</gsx:NAME>
<gsx:CITY>sajdkajsncn</gsx:CITY>
<gsx:STATE>sdlksjdsaj</gsx:STATE>
<gsx:EMAIL>dkajslkdjsajdasj</gsx:EMAIL>
<gsx:ZIP>ascmnanjcna</gsx:ZIP>
<gsx:ADDRESS>sadhbaskjdjashjkdhas</gsx:ADDRESS>
<gsx:NOTES>ncjansjkhnkn</gsx:NOTES>

</entry>
";
echo $google->writeSheet($xml);
```

It works perfect before but now I am getting an error

Blank rows cannot be written; use delete instead.

Thanks in advance.